# Manipulating 2 pandas dataframe to find a match and return the index

Tags: pandas

I have 2 dataframe.

first :

```
         AGATC  AATG  TATC
name                      
Alice        2     8     3
Bob          4     1     5
Charlie      3     2     5
```

second :

```
   AGATC  AATG  TATC
0      4     1     5
```

I did a merge but the index name is gone.
I want to do a match and return Bob as the output.

How should I go about it? Sorry i have issues how to display the dataframe properly.

Thanks.

Comment: `df1[df1.eq(df2.iloc[0])].index`?

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `numpy` broadcast

```
df1.index[np.all(df1.values==df2.values[:,None], axis = 2)[0]]
Out[237]: Index(['Bob'], dtype='object', name='name')
```